# 9-patch image not working correctly on Android 4.1.2?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a simple 9-patch image as below

[image: 9 Patch Shadow]

My layout code as below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#DD0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/tooltip_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shadow"

        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When it get run on Android 4.1.2 (v16), the image is as below

[image: Android 4.1.2 (v16) result]

When it get run on Android 4.2.2 (v17) or larger, the image is as below, which is the expected result.
[image: Android 4.2.2 (v17) result]

Is this a bug in Android 4.1.2, or it need special handling of 9-patch image? Hopes someone could shed some light.

Note: I could workaround it using values-v17 dimen settings on it. But though would like to understand why. Thanks!!

Comment: maybe the devices you test on have different dpi and use different images (and you have an error in image for one dpi)

Comment: Hi @Anton, this is tested on 2 different devices, ie Sony Xperia and Galaxy S2, which have different dpi and resolution. The are the same using Android 4.1.2, having the problem. Other devices which have newer Android version don't have the problem. To prove my understanding right, I finally decide to use identical Nexus 5 emulator, with just the Android version different. Indeed, they behave as the picture (those are shown above)